Sitecore 9.3 installation giving error, any idea?

not able to install sitecore version 9, giving the error from screen, any idea? is this installation no longer supported?

What is in the log file?

I think the answer un this article may help: https://community.sitecore.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=d10043b31be205d0e55241dde54bcbcf
In short, replace the following in prerequisites.json
"WebPlatformDownload": {
   "Type": "String",
   "Description": "Download location of Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0",
   "DefaultValue": "https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/9/849DBCF2-DFD9-49F5-9A19-9AEE5B29341A/WebPlatformInstaller_x64_en-US.msi"
},

Or try direct link to download: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/web-platform-installer/web-platform-installer-direct-downloads

thank you that solved
